# Recyclerview swipe ondismiss animation fail

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with ItemTouchHelper swipe remove action. If I enter in the Activity, and swipe, then  all works ok. But if I open a second Activity, and push the back button,or  I open the Intent with ActivityForResult, and back data and  call finish(), then the item is deleted, but no animation is viewed. A blank space left in the RecyclerView. If I open the second Activity , and use Homeup function in the ActionBar,then  the swipe works correctly.

What I am doing wrong ?

OnResume Code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        final ImageView editAccount = (ImageView)                 findViewById(R.id.account_edit);

        listaCuentas = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        listaCuentas.setHasFixedSize(true);
        listaCuentas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        listaCuentas.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        cuentasDS = new AccountsDataSource(this.getApplicationContext());
        cuentasDS.open();
        listaCuentas.setAdapter(new AccountsAdapter(cuentasDS.getAllAccounts(), this));
        cuentasDS.close();
        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback((ItemTouchHelperAdapter)listaCuentas.getAdapter());
        ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(listaCuentas);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```